# Product Sales Report weekly monthly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i run a SQL query to retrieve weekly  and monthly sales reports.

**Table: orders**

### ID |Product_id | order price | QTY | purchase date

```
1        1           34         2        9/10/12
2        1           34         2        8/10/12
3        4           34         2        07/10/12
4        3           34         2        22/09/12
5        1           34         2        9/10/12
6        1           34         2        22/09/12
7        4           34         2        9/08/12
8        3           34         2        22/09/12
```

**Table: Products**

```
ID | Name | description

1    A       ksfjsdkf
2    B       ksfjsdkf
3    C       ksfjsdkf
1    A       ksfjsdkf
```

**Expecting result**
:the following is an example result not accurate

```
product_name           Weekly Sum(QTY), weekly revenue,  Monthly SUM(QTY), monthly revenue

A                           120             3000           2345                  234343
```

Comment: how can we help you if you have not provided the structure of the table, sample records?

Comment: Without schemas and their relationships nobody will help you out !

Comment: sorry guys, i have added some example tables

Comment: When you refer to "weekly" and "monthly" data in your output, what do you mean?  The last 7 and 31 days?  The most recent complete calendar week and month?  The current, incomplete calendar week and month?  Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: @MohammadHossain Can you please tell me how to calculate the revenue e.g. the first row in table orders (it the same to the rest)?

Comment: weekly = this week report, monthly: this month total sales

Comment: @MohammadHossain: But what do you mean by "*this week*" and "*this month*"?  Today is Sunday 21 October.  Is "*this week*" just today?  Is "*this month*" the 21 days of October so far?

Comment: weekly Revenue: total order price (if u add whole week order prices for a product u will find the weekly revenue for a product). Similarly u will find out the yearly revenue.

Comment: @ eggyal , for monthly, 21 days report enough. if u prefer please give last week and last month report. its alright. i just wanna know the correct method for generating weekly and monthly reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here a simple Query for the Quantities and Order Price

```
SELECT p.Description, psw.qtysum, psw.opsum, psm.qtysum, psm.opsum
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT sw.product_id, SUM( sw.QTY ) AS qtysum, SUM( sw.`order price` ) AS opsum 
    FROM orders sw 
    WHERE WEEK( sw.`purchase date`) = WEEK( current_date )
    AND YEAR( sw.`purchase date`) = YEAR( current_date )
    GROUP BY sw.product_id ) psw 
  ON p.id = psw.product_id

LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT sm.product_id, SUM( sm.QTY ) AS qtysum, SUM( sm.`order price` ) AS opsum 
    FROM orders sm 
    WHERE MONTH( sm.`purchase date`) = MONTH( current_date )
    AND YEAR( sm.`purchase date`) = YEAR( current_date )
    GROUP BY sm.product_id ) psm 
  ON p.id = psm.product_id
```

Comment: I see a problem with this, which is that if your database contains more than 1 year worth of orders, it will add the same months and weeks from previous years. Add a year check as well.

Comment: @TorValamo you are right and i changed it, thanx for reporting :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can use php datetime("W") to get the weeknumber and datetime("m") to get the month number then convert all dates in your database to weeknumber and monthnumber and sort it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name, week.qty, week.price, month.qty, month.price
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT p.id AS prod_id, SUM(o.qty) AS qty, SUM(o.price) AS price
   FROM products p LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.id = o.prod_id
   WHERE o.date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 day)
   GROUP BY p.id) AS week ON p.id = week.prod_id LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT p.id AS prod_id, SUM(o.qty) AS qty, SUM(o.price) AS price
   FROM products p LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.id = o.prod_id
   WHERE o.date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 month)
   GROUP BY p.id) AS month ON p.id = month.prod_id
```

Not too optimized, but I don't have a mysql cli here so I won't post any more intricate stuff that might not even work without having the ability to testi t.

Comment: There's always http://sqlfiddle.com :)